# Using IF & ELSE in Drupal

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a twig template where I am displaying certain details based on the type of person.
But the condition is not working, I'm just wondering what is wrong with the `IF` clause?

```
{% if field_person_type == 'XXXXXXX' %}{{ (content.field_position) }}, {{ (content.field_unit) }}
{% else %} {{ (content.field_position) }}, {{ (content.field_institution) }} {% endif %}
```

And the `content` is defined below

```
Position    field_position      Text            Text field  
Person Type field_person_type   Term reference  Check boxes/radio buttons
Unit        field_unit          Text            Text field  
Institution field_institution   Term reference  Check boxes/radio buttons
```

When I use `dump(field_person_type)`, it shows following

```
ARRAY(1) { 
    [0]=> ARRAY(2) { 
        ["TID"]=> STRING(2) "40"
        ["TAXONOMY_TERM"]=> OBJECT(STDCLASS)#179 (8) { 
            ["TID"]=> STRING(2) "40" 
            ["VID"]=> STRING(1) "5"
            ["NAME"]=> STRING(7) "XXXXXXX" 
            ["DESCRIPTION"]=> STRING(0) "" 
            ["FORMAT"]=> STRING(2) "21" 
            ["WEIGHT"]=> STRING(1) "2" 
            ["VOCABULARY_MACHINE_NAME"]=> STRING(11) "PERSON_TYPE"
            ["PATH"]=> ARRAY(1) { 
                ["PATHAUTO"]=> STRING(1) "1" 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you already verify the contents of `field_person_type`, you can try to do `dump(filed_person_type)` if you have debug enabled to watch whats really inside the variable

Comment: @DarkBee I updated the `dump()` result in the question. I can `XXX` after `STRING(7)` and at the end.

Comment: Not sure how `XXX` can be 7 string long but you would need to change the`if` to: `{% if field_person_type.name | trim == 'XXX' %}` as you can see, ``field_person_type` is an array, not a string

Comment: Yes, it is 7 char long string. I am sorry, I masked the original value with `X`s. I am bit confused with this array representation.  The `field_person_type.name` is not working :(

Comment: When I use `dump(field_person_type.name)`, it gives me `NULL`

Comment: Sorry, `field_person_type.TAXONOMY_TERM.name`

Comment: That too gives me `NULL`  :(

Comment: `field_person_type[0].TAXONOMY_TERM.name` ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this  `field_person_type.0.taxonomy_term.name`

Answer (score 0):

Twig cannot access the name magically, you have to access it like you would access an array.

As the dump states: Your field (field_person_type) is an array. Inside you have [0] which is also an array with 2 entries. The "TAXONOMY_TERM" inside is an object so should be accessed as an object.

The following should give you your result

```
field_person_type[0]["TAXONOMY_TERM"].NAME
```

Comment: It still gives me `NULL`